# 404 Error Not Found

Tags: python, flask, twilio

I am new to flask and twilio and I am getting a 404 error running my app (I am following this tutorial: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/01/making-an-sms-birthday-card-with-python-and-flask.html) . I have googled this and search stack overflow but I can not fix it. Below is my code:

```
from flask import Flask
import os


app = Flask(__name__)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))

    if port == 5000:
        app.debug = True

    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

And I get this error:
   404 Not Found

## Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please  check your spelling and try again.

I am running my app from the terminal by going:
    python app.py

Answer (score 2):

You don't have any route mapping

```
from flask import Flask
import os


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))

    if port == 5000:
        app.debug = True

    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

Comment: Note, add this in the body of your python script. That is, before the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block.

Comment: Still getting 404 error. This is what I get in my terminal:     127.0.0.1 - - [02/Oct/2014 20:37:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: What are you typing into your browser address bar?